# mod_rewrite doesn't work as I want even with JSON API Plugin disabled

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, plugin-json-api

I've been asked to upgrade the codebase of a Wordpress website, which exposes a small set of APIs using [JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).

The Wordpress installation is not in the root, but in a secondary folder:

```
/root
  test/new_api.php
  wordpress/  <<-----
  index.php
```

And the JSON API plugin was set to intercept external GET requests like this:

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/something
```

For several reasons, I've decided to change the way the API is called by using a PHP code written by me, instead of relying on that plugin. The PHP scripts that will handle the requests are now stored in `/test/new_api.php`.

Hence, my goal is to redirect the requests this way:

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/something  ---->  http://www.example.com/test/new_api.php?req=something
```

To do that, I opened the .htaccess file on the root and I added a new line (# BEGIN new API):

```
RewriteEngine on
....

# BEGIN new API
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /test/new_api.php?req=/$1 [L,QSA]
# END new API

# BEGIN Wordpress
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
# END Wordpress
```

I have one question + one problem:

1. I never used the JSON API before, so I'm a beginner here, but... How can it intercept the requests on /api/v1/... if there are no lines on the .htaccess file that say it? I expected to see something like `RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /wordpress/wp-content....`.
2. Anyway the real problem is that the new rule I've added doesn't work. If I request `http://www.example.com/api/v1/something`, it continues to call the old api provided by the plugin! I've also tried to disable JSON API, but now the result is the 404 error page of Wordpress.

Doesn't .htaccess have the priority over all other "url rewrite" systems? Does the JSON API have changed some other settings around?

Comment: The plugin intercepts requests the same way all other pretty permalinks function within WordPress, using the default rewrite rules in the .htaccess file. perhaps it would be better to describe what problem you are trying to solve by using your own php file rather than ask about the solution you think you need.